# Install Stylus manually from .zip file

Tags: node.js, proxy, installation, stylus, manual

i have a problem installing stylus through npm install because of the proxy settings of my network.  I want to know how to install stylus manually with the .zip file that i just downloaded from their github.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you should put all content of this archive in `$NODE_PATH/stylus` folder:

```
cd $NODE_PATH
mkdir stylus
cd stylus
<copy all here>
```

Then you should symlink `bin/stylus` from this folder to some dir in your `PATH` variable, for example `/usr/local/bin/` (if you on Linux or OS X):

```
ln -s bin/stylus /usr/local/bin/stylus
```

That's all.

P.S.: You can configure npm to use proxy. See http://jjasonclark.com/how-to-setup-node-behind-web-proxy for detail information.